# How do I display an API's data with Python?

Tags: python, html, api

I am quite new with using API's and working with Python, but what I want to achieve is to display my data I receive from my Json request in HTML on my site with Python, how do I go about displaying the data? For now I only have generated a request from the API and receive a Json response.

---

```
# Import the modules
import requests
import json



# Get the feed
rtrans =    requests.get("https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/top_google_charts.json?list_name=topselling_free&cat_key=TRANSPORTATION&country=DK&limit=10&access_token=f033114ffaa48a2d31139bd1eb55d9fc54ed6729")
rtrans.text

# Convert it to a Python dictionary
datatransportation = json.loads(rtrans.text)

print datatransportation
```

My code looks like this currently.

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: Are you using a web framework like Flask or Django? If so, you can just write out the JSON data to HTML

Comment: Code added, I am not using a framework, should I instead make a new script with Flask and generate a request with it and go from there?

Comment: It seems like you are pretty new to this. I suggest you use Flask or Django, and start over.

Comment: Another web framework is [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html). It is not for production environments, but it is an easy and simple one you can start with.

Comment: Yeah, I am totally new to this and python as a whole, just went through the codeacademy course, but want to practice more things in order to get a better grasp of it, I will try the Flask framework and see how it goes! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the `urllib2` library when I access API data, but the `requests` library is very similar.

Here is the code I would use with the `urllib2` library:

```
import urllib2
import json

access_token = "<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>"
url_address = "https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/top_google_charts.json?list_name=topselling_free&cat_key=TRANSPORTATION&country=DK&limit=10&access_token=" + access_token

url_content_as_text = urllib2.urlopen(url_address).read()
url_content_as_json = json.loads(url_content_as_text)
print url_content_as_json
```

Here is the code I would use with the `requests` library:

```
import requests

access_token = "<YOUR ACCESS TOKEN>"
url_address = "https://42matters.com/api/1/apps/top_google_charts.json?list_name=topselling_free&cat_key=TRANSPORTATION&country=DK&limit=10&access_token=" + access_token

url_content = requests.get(url_address)
print url_content.json()
```